# facebook sharing using php

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have one page on that page having multiple images.On each image have their own share and like button.when i click on share button i want to share that perticular image but that is not happening please help me.
here is my code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var str;
        function fbs_click(u,val)
        {
            var i;

            var imgobj=document.getElementById(val).getElementsByTagName('img');
            for(i=0;i<imgobj.length;i++){
                str=imgobj[i].src;
                //document.write("<br>");
            }
            alert(str);
            //This is to show fb popup for sharing passed pageurl
            window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
            return false;
        }
    </script>

<!--This is for setting img for fb like -->
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg"  href="'+str+'">');</script>


$url="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<div class='sharebutton'>
                            <a href='#' onclick='return fbs_click(\"$url\",\"$src_value\");' class='fb_share_link'>Share on Facebook</a>
                        </div>
```

i have paste the code is short just understand you my problem

Comment: funnycatimages.net //refer this site for my above question

Comment: i always refer sites only for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're only sending the page url. Facebook indexes its like counts based on the url.

Since Facebook has no idea which image on the page the user is intending to share, it grabs your default meta tags for the page and that's what shows up on the user's timeline. Since the urls for each photo are the same, sharing any one photo will result in the counter being incremented for all photos.

One way to make this work would be to create a separate page for each image on your site and pass that in your onclick function. That page has specific metadata for that image the Facebook parser can use. When a user follows that link, have a script on that page to redirect them back to your main page (preferably to an anchor at the right photo). You'll need to have some way to fail gracefully for people who don't have javascript enabled.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.
will you please give me an example on this please...
it ill very helpfull to me 
Thank you very much

Comment: You already have detail pages for each photo. Just set your FB Like url under each photo to the matching url of the detail page: `../1/`, `../2/`, etc.